# Save and load object data in database

Tags: php

I need some solution to save object state in database. Originally, this data was BLOB, from which was retrieved and restored, but right now it can't work like this.

Newly there could be some changes to these objects and also I would like to have a changes comparison.
After some time these data are deleted, but this time can vary from days to weeks and during this time of period there can be request to perform changes or compare these changes.

I think that array with keys and values is the best compromise for comparisons and performing changes in such structure.
So what is a better solution?

Convert object to associative array, serialize data and write for each type of object some version of hydrator and converter? 
Or use some general logic which could go through objects with reflection and create this array to and back?

I couldn't find a solution to this online. Not for this type of dynamic changes and comparisons.

Comment: Start by checking the PHP manual for `serialize()` and `unserialize()` or `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` both can be used on Objects to dehydrate and rehydrate the properties to and from a string

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.7+ you could also use a JSON column type which allows you to process the Json string from within a query

Comment: I'm aware of these serialization methods. But with these types of serialization I would only change a way how is it stored in database. 
Store whole serialized objects like this has many disadvantages.
And I'm more like change it to saving only necessary data. That's where I got the idea of storing only key => value pairs from which later on object can be constructed, where key would be the property name. In this case I could better control what should be stored in database. The only think is if use custom class for each type of stored object or use reflection to access properties.

Comment: Surely if you dehydrate only a part of an object, when you come to rehydrate an object using only some of its properties you run the risk of missing something a) useful and b) required for the object to perform correctly when rehydrated

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the JsonSerializable interface. Just looked it up with your suggestions. Now I think your idea is perfect for me. Thank you.